# Filter user list that meta_value is empty

Tags: wp-query, users

I am trying to get all users that meta value is empty

so i tried many variations and cant get the list of all user that birthday field is empty (not set).

```
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_key']     = 'birthday';
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_value']   = '';
        //or
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_value']   = Null;
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';
```

Comment: First, as a general observation, take notice that you are altering all of the queries so make sure you are altering only the one(s) that you need. Second, do the posts actually have that `birthday` `meta_key` with an empty `meta_value` in the `wp_postmeta` table? Or you want to fetch only those IDs that don't have that `meta_key` / `meta_value` at all set in the `wp_postmeta` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the use of `meta_query` is in order:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array( 
        'meta_query'=> array( 
            array( 
                 'key'=> 'birthday', 
                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' 
            ) 
        ) 
     ) 
);
```

Basically, this looks for all users where the meta key of `birthday` doesn't have a value ie doesn't exist.  More info about meta queries in `WP_User_Query` can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)